# issues with memcpy on android when using offset for the source

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I am working on an android app using JNI.

I keep sending `byte[]` from java and it arrives as a `jbyteArray` in cpp.

To get from the `jbyteArray` to a `signed char*` i use this function:

```
jbyte* content_array = (env)->GetByteArrayElements(array,NULL);
```

(`jbyte*` is just a typedef of `signed char*`)

Now i did run into problems when trying to access the data at the `signed char*` pointer at later times. 
It think at some point the java garbage collector kicks in and frees the memory, so i can no longer access it.

To work around this issue, i am now copying the incoming data like this:

```
    // newJavaByteData is the signed char* coming in from java
    signed char* buffer = new signed char[length];
    memcpy(buffer, newJavaByteData, length);
    //javaByteData is a std::vector<signed char*>
    javaByteData.push_back(buffer);
```

So far so good. 
At later frames i can read the data and when i do not need it any more, i delete it like this:

```
        int frame_cnt=0;
        while(frame_cnt<javaByteData.size()){
            delete javaByteData[frame_cnt++];
        }
        javaByteData.clear();
```

Now i need to extract chunks of bytes from this data.
Again i am using `memcpy` to extract the needed portion of the bytes.

This time i need to apply a offset to the source-pointer

```
    char* extractedBytes[lengthOfBytes];
    //originalJavaData is the signed char* i did alloc and memcpy into earlier
    memcpy(extractedBytes, &originalJavaData[offset], lengthOfBytes* sizeof(char));
```

This is working well, until its not :(

I can extract data this way, but when the amount of bytes i extract exceed some limit, i am getting this error:

```
SIGSEGV (signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x53))
```

The fault address varies with each time i run the app message.

I am not yet sure what the limit is, but i can extract 262144 bytes (256x256x4) just fine, while extracting 1048576 bytes (1024x1024x4) is causing the crash / signal.

I was thinking the issue was that i am running out of memory in the cpp thread, but i can happily alloc more memory. just the `memcpy` is failing.

I think i could set up a eventHandler for the SIGSEGV signals, but i have no experience with that, and also i already tracked the issue down to the usage of `memcpy`, so i hope it just a thing i am doing wrong with memcpy.

I am thinking that maybe its a problem with memory not aligned correctly  and thus the `memcpy` is failing due to the fact that i add the offset to the source-pointer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to do this. The returned data may already be a copy and in any case the result is valid until you call `ReleaseByteArrayElements()`. See the [JNI Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#Get_PrimitiveType_ArrayElements_routines). You should go back to investigating your original problem.

Comment: Yeah. thanks. i did look at the docs again, and i found that GetByteArrayRegion is taken care of the copying already. I think my issue might be really running out of memory...well...still investigating..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I found the problem.

It seem that i was running out of stack memory, while when i use heap memory i am good to go.

So instead of this lines:

```
char* extractedBytes[lengthOfBytes];
//originalJavaData is the signed char* i did alloc and memcpy into earlier
memcpy(extractedBytes, &originalJavaData[offset], lengthOfBytes* sizeof(char));
```

i now have this:

```
char* extractedBytes = new char[lengthOfBytes];
//originalJavaData is the signed char* i did alloc and memcpy into earlier
memcpy(extractedBytes, &originalJavaData[offset], lengthOfBytes* sizeof(char));
```

`memcpy` is now doing its job and extracts portions of the `signed char*` without complaining.

Of course by allocating the memory on the heap, i now have to take care of disposing my data later.

On a sidenote: I stopped copying the incoming data myself, and instead of `GetByteArrayElements` i am now using `GetByteArrayRegion` which is doing the copying for me.

Hope i do not get downvoted for answering my own question again. For me this is a valid solution to my problem.